# How can i stop my animation circle ? - JS

Tags: javascript

i'm doing a game with javascript only using function, i know it's not the best method but i'm  still learning prototypes before steping in to use them. So, to the point, i have a request animatation frame that calls him self so my function keep executing. The problem is when the player dies i want to stop the enemys to be created , basicaly, stop the functions execution. Better show you some code. 
This is my animation function:

```
    function animate() {


        if (endGame() == true) {
            return;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        if(theBird == null && canContinue == true) {
            theBird = getBird(); // variavel com a div do bird
            setTimeout(createDrake(), Math.round(Math.random() * 800));
            setTimeout(createBrick(), Math.round(Math.random() * 3000));
            setTimeout(createBoss(), Math.round(1000 + Math.random() * 15000));
            setTimeout(createPowerUp(),  Math.round(Math.random() * 15000));


            document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPressed);
            document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyReleased);  

    }
        else {
            updateBirdLocation();
            updateBirdSpeed();

            flyDrakes();
            flyBrick();
            flyBullets();
            flyPowerUp();
            flyBoss();

            checkBulletCollisions();
            checkBulletCollisionsBricks()   
            checkShipCollision();
            checkShipCollisionBricks();
            checkShipCollisionBonusP();

             checkShipCollisionBoss();
             checkBulletCollisionsBoss();

            updateScores();

            checkEnemyBulletCollisions();
            MoveArrayX(bullets2, -10);
            MoveArrayX(bullets3, -10);
            removePassingElements();




         }

}
```

And this one is my function stopGame that is beeing called everytime player looses:

```
function endGame() {

    Rbutton.style.visibility= "visible";
    var RestartDiv = document.createElement("div");

    RestartDiv.id =  "RestartDiv";

    gameDiv.appendChild(RestartDiv);

    document.getElementById('RestartDiv').innerHTML += "You scored" + "  " + mobHits + " " + "points!";
    canContinue = false;

    return true; 



}
```

My attemp to stop this was the 1st part of animate :

```
function animate() {


        if (endGame() == true) {
            return;
        }
```

but if i do this my game stops ( like i want ) but before the player dies.

I do not have endGame beeing executed anywhere besides the functions where the player dies. How can i solve this ?

Thank you

EDIT: This is an example how i detect a player died:

```
function checkShipCollisionBoss() { 
        for (var k=0; k<bossArray.length; k++) {
            if ((isCollide(BirdsDiv, bossArray[k]) ) == true){
                        endGame();

            }           

    }
}
```

isCollide is a function that detects the collision.

Comment: Seems like your endGame function always returns true. There is no condition checking whether the player died or not.

Comment: yeah just what i thought but she isnt, i checked everywhere. I'll edit the post to show you a example how i detect that player died.

Answer (score 3):

Then do like this,

```
    function endGame() { 

     if(isCollide())    // return a boolean from this function
     {
           Rbutton.style.visibility= "visible";
           var RestartDiv = document.createElement("div");

           RestartDiv.id =  "RestartDiv";

           gameDiv.appendChild(RestartDiv);

           document.getElementById('RestartDiv').innerHTML += "You scored" + "  " + mobHits + " " + "points!";
          canContinue = false;

          return true; 
     }

    return false;
  }
```

Also remember this, if you are going to check a boolean you can simple give

```
if(true) or if (false)
```

Example,

```
   var bool    = true;

   if(bool)
      // your stuff
```

Comment: Thank you, but that dosn't work, endGame is only executed if isCollide = true already in the function isCollide, but anyway i tried like you said but didnt worked for me

Comment: change that isCollide to checkShipCollisionBoss, i didnt see that you are passing two params to that isCollide

Comment: And also you are checking some other collisions. what are those?

Comment: I have several checkCollision for different enemies / bullets / walls, so i dont know if that's the best solution. Atm i'm trying to work with the "canContinue" variable wich is a boolean that change to false when game is lost. If i do                           '  if (canContinue == false) {
            window.alert("it works");
        }'   i see the alert when i die. But if i put return, the animation still creates the enemies.

Comment: Ok got it. If that canContinue is a global variable, make it as false when eve the user dies. So in the function animate, change the condition like if(!canContinue){endGame();return;}

Comment: I did like you said and it makes all the logic and sense to work, and in part it does because when the player dies i get my function to show the Play again button executed but still the enemies get created. For some reason it does not stop the animation circle. Isn't that returns job ? Thank you for the help btw

Comment: its the setTimeout which is causing it to create more enemies. Clear it in the endGame function.... and remove returns from the endGame() function and also check whether you are making canContinue to be true in anyone of those create function

Comment: Hmm good point ! So, i made variables for all the setTimeout i have and in the function endgame i made `clearTimeout(e1); clearTimeout(e2); ... ` I also removed the return from the endGame() function. I checked canContinue and it is working perfectly. Dispite all thoose atemps they dont stop :|

Comment: put it in jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: Btw, the endGame() function is on the html ! forgot to change

Comment: Check this link http://tornadobird.url.ph/ I uploaded the game so you can see better the error in the end i want to correct

Answer (score 1):

Your endGame function always return true, so endGame() == true

Then in animate function:

```
function animate() {

        if (endGame() == true) {
            return;
        }

        ...
 }
```

which is:

```
function animate() {

        if (true == true) {
            return;
        }

        ...
 }
```

which is:

```
function animate() {

        if (true) {
            return;
        }

        ...
 }
```

which is:

```
function animate() {

        return;

        ...
 }
```

So it always return

Comment: Point taken and i understand the error ! Looking for the answer now :D